# Using Spree Deface Overrides, how do I change the css class of a submit tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, deface

So in my code I have the following on line 14:

*app/views/spree/shared/_search.html.erb*

```
<%= submit_tag Spree.t(:search), name: nil, class: "btn btn-danger" %>
```

and in:

*app/overrides/edit_header.rb*

```
Deface::Override.new(
  :virtual_path   => "spree/shared/_search",
  :name           => "set_button_to_green",
  :set_attributes => "erb[loud]:contains('submit_tag')",
  :attributes     => { :class => "btn btn-info" }
)
```

and while it sorta works, here are the results:

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

I have spent several hours today trying to troubleshoot this issue, and I haven't found any answers that specifically address my issue. At the moment I have a work-around, but understanding this issue would really speed up my process.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I've got it working.

While I was using the `:set_attributes` and `:attributes` settings, the output ended up producing the following in the HTML output:

```
<erb loud class="btn btn-info">
  submit_tag Spree.t(:search), name: nil, class: "btn btn-danger" %&gt;
</erb>
```

What actually worked is the following:

```
Deface::Override.new(
  :virtual_path => "spree/shared/_search",
  :name => "set_button_to_green",
  :replace => "erb[loud]:contains('submit_tag')",
  :text => "<%= submit_tag Spree.t(:search), name: nil, class: 'btn btn-info' %>"
)
```

So using `:replace` and `:text` is what I needed rather than just setting the attributes.